# JENKINS BUILD ERROR fatal error C1853: precompiled header error

Tags: c++, jenkins

When I run a new build using Jenkins I get the following error:

> "FilePathY\XXX.cpp : fatal error C1853: 'FilePathZ\XXX.pch'
>   precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or
>   the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C."

Nothing had changed in the project since the previous build. There was no logical reason why was suddenly failing the build.

(You should note that made several changes to some files a different project under the solution. 
But the project failing with the file FilePath1\XXXX.cpp did not undergo any changes, nor its dependencies either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a backup of your pch file.. and delete it. Then rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Many times this can occur due to old workspace precompiled header files.
These files exist from a previous build (an older version) and were not being cleaned.

In order to clean these files you need to:

1. Open the failing build job.
2. Click on the 'Workspace' link on the upper left hand side.
3. Click on 'Wipe Out Current Workspace'.

   [image]
4. A pop up message will appear asking "Are you sure about wiping out the workspace?"
5. Click the 'OK' button.
6. Rebuild your project.